# Reference a subset of a column in a CSV

Tags: ruby, csv

I want to bring a row-column CSV file into Ruby and then perform operations like reduce on sequential rows of a single column in that data. Something like:

```
Array[startrow..endrow][3].reduce(:+)
```

I can bring in a CSV file and do mathematics on a specific cell, like:

```
Array[somerow][somecolumn]/2
```

but I get the "...no implicit conversion of string into integer" error when I try to reference a subset.

Edit: I am importing the CSV using the following, which appears to be correctly converting strings to numbers:

```
array = CSV.read('spy_very_short.txt', :headers => true, converters: :all)
```

When I run the suggested test

```
array[somerow][somecolumn].class
```

I get back "float".

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about what is returned (I assume it's always a string representing a number), I think you need to convert the string into something you can do math with:

```
value = Array[somerow][somecolumn]
print value.to_i / 2
```

The [`to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-to_i) method on the String class does its best to convert the string into an integer which you can then to math on.

If there will be decimal places in the data, you probably want [`to_f`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-to_f) instead, converting it into a float.

Answer (score 0):

```
Array[somerow][somecolumn]
```

is returning a String object probably.

Verify this by:

```
puts Array[somerow][somecolumn].class
```

I run into this type of issue often when doing data processing in Ruby. It is useful to check that the right objects are passed arround.

Comment: thank you, I edited my question to say that I'm running converters on my CSV and they seem to work -- when I run the check you suggested I get back "float."

Comment: Double check this part Array[startrow..endrow][3], does it return what you are expecting? It will return Array[startrow+3] Not an array of column 3 values.

Comment: Also check that you are not reducing over the header. The header is probably text.

Comment: The headers >= true seems to be successfully removing the headers from the reduce. The Array[startrow..endrow][3] example does not seem to return what I want; I think that's part of my problem.